# Storing my desktop in summer heat

Tags: windows, temperature

I am in the Houston Texas area and I am storing my computers in a non climate controlled storage unit in the dead of summer temperatures are reaching @ 100 f so I would think it is probably @ 150f in the unit I may be wrong, they have been there @ 2months now. My question is how long and how much heat can they endure, I would think the cold would be more dangerous than the heat but has anyone got any experience with this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat wont be an issue.  The question in my mind is the humidity down there.  The metals might corrode if exposed to enough water in the air.  I would wrap the computers tightly in plastic and store the computers in an airtight container.  It couldnt hurt to put in some of those [silica gel dessicants](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DKQB02).

Comment: You can even buy large plastic bags which can be used to vacuum pack (the air can be sucked out with a vacuum cleaner). I've have a couple that I use to fit more clothes in a suitcase when travelling. They are large enough to contain a desktop tower. They give a very good air seal.

Comment: I used to live in Houston when I was young and I remember all kinds of bugs (those German Cockroaches were huge) would get into *anything* stored outside (and even inside).  Sealing them up with multiple layers would be prudent.